# AdMob ads not displaying - LogCat says ads are received

Tags: admob, logcat, ads, banner

I added AdMob code to my Android game but ads doesnt display. Checked the LogCat and ads are received, looked my AdMob account and game turn green, request is good with 100% fill rate. I did not touch xml, just onCreate. Please tell me if something I can do in xml or anything else. I putted all permissions in manifest. Please look and help, having trouble already 10 days. Thank you

My code:

```
Window window = getWindow();
    RelativeLayout adsLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     // Displays Ads at the bottom of your sketch, use Gravity.TOP to display them at the top
    adsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "myid");  // add your app-id
    adsLayout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest newAdReq = new AdRequest();
    //Remark: uncomment next line for testing your Ads (fake ads)
    newAdReq.setTesting(false);
    adView.loadAd(newAdReq);
    window.addContentView(adsLayout,lp2);
```

Android Manifest:

> 

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity android:name=".MYGAMENAME"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

My Main.xml:

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       android:orientation="vertical"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: Post your layout code also. Show how you have put the admob in your layout ?

Comment: Where have you provided your `ads:adUnitId="YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID HERE"` ?